# Checking radiogroup radio button deselects radio button?

Tags: jquery

I have a series of tabs that have a large number of radiogroups for answers (Y/N/U/NA). When a user selects a select filter option it hides certain tabs.  I want to set the default radio button for each radiogroup on those tabs to NA.  When I loop through each radio button I check to see if the value is NA.  If it is, I try to check that radio button.  When I flip back the filter option so I can navigate to the tab, I see the radiogroups that were previously NOT NA (ex: Y) unchecked all together.

```
if (fatalityType == 'P') {
    SelectNARadio($("#suicide input:radio, #child input:radio"));
    $("#SuicideFactorsTab, #ChildFactorsTab").hide();
}

function SelectNARadio(target) {
    //target.find("[value='NA']").click().change(); // doesn't work
    target.each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "NA") {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you add `html` and `CSS` so we can check how this is working?